# Initialising a multidimensional array in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

What is the correct way to declare a multidimensional array and assign values to it?

This is what I have:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 5;

String[][] myStringArray = new String [x][y];

myStringArray[0][x] = "a string";
myStringArray[0][y] = "another string";
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try replacing the appropriate lines with:

```
myStringArray[0][x-1] = "a string";
myStringArray[0][y-1] = "another string";
```

Your code is incorrect because the sub-arrays have a length of `y`, and indexing starts at 0. So setting to `myStringArray[0][y]` or `myStringArray[0][x]` will fail because the indices `x` and `y` are out of bounds.

`String[][] myStringArray = new String [x][y];` is the correct way to initialise a rectangular multidimensional array. If you want it to be jagged (each sub-array potentially has a different length) then you can use code similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067073/java-multidimensional-array/1067087#1067087). Note however that John's assertion that you have to create the sub-arrays manually is incorrect in the case where you want a perfectly rectangular multidimensional array.

Answer (score 108):

Java doesn't have "true" multidimensional arrays.

For example, `arr[i][j][k]` is equivalent to `((arr[i])[j])[k]`. In other words, `arr` is simply **an array, of arrays, of arrays**.

So, if you know how arrays work, you know how multidimensional arrays work!

---

**Declaration:**

```
int[][][] threeDimArr = new int[4][5][6];
```

or, with initialization:

```
int[][][] threeDimArr = { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }, { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } };
```

---

**Access:**

```
int x = threeDimArr[1][0][1];
```

or

```
int[][] row = threeDimArr[1];
```

---

**String representation:**

```
Arrays.deepToString(threeDimArr);
```

yields

```
"[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]"
```

### Useful articles

- [Java: Initializing a multidimensional array](https://programming.guide/java/initialize-multidimensional-array.html)
- [Java: Matrices and Multidimensional Arrays](https://programming.guide/java/matrices-and-multidimensional-arrays.html)

Comment: How is that not a "true" multidimensional array?

Comment: With "true" multidimensional arrays I refer to "non-jagged" arrays. For the difference between jagged arrays and "true" multidimensional arrays, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c).

Comment: An `int[i][j][k]` has length `i`, so really it's equivalent to an `((int[k])[j])[i]`. The sizes in the declaration are written backwards with respect to the types, I suppose to make multidimensional arrays more closely resemble matrices in mathematics.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Arrays.deepToString.

Answer (score 60):

You can also use the following construct:

```
String[][] myStringArray = new String [][] { { "X0", "Y0"},
                                             { "X1", "Y1"},
                                             { "X2", "Y2"},
                                             { "X3", "Y3"},
                                             { "X4", "Y4"} };
```

Answer (score 13):

You can declare multi dimensional arrays like :

```
// 4 x 5 String arrays, all Strings are null
// [0] -> [null,null,null,null,null]
// [1] -> [null,null,null,null,null]
// [2] -> [null,null,null,null,null]
// [3] -> [null,null,null,null,null]

String[][] sa1 = new String[4][5];
for(int i = 0; i < sa1.length; i++) {           // sa1.length == 4
    for (int j = 0; j < sa1[i].length; j++) {     //sa1[i].length == 5
        sa1[i][j] = "new String value";
    }
}


// 5 x 0  All String arrays are null
// [null]
// [null]
// [null]
// [null]
// [null]
String[][] sa2 = new String[5][];
for(int i = 0; i < sa2.length; i++) {
    String[] anon = new String[ /* your number here */];
    // or String[] anon = new String[]{"I'm", "a", "new", "array"};
    sa2[i] = anon;
}

// [0] -> ["I'm","in","the", "0th", "array"]
// [1] -> ["I'm", "in", "another"]
String[][] sa3 = new String[][]{ {"I'm","in","the", "0th", "array"},{"I'm", "in", "another"}};
```

Answer (score 9):

### Multidimensional Array in Java

#### Returning a multidimensional array

Java does not ***truely*** support multidimensional arrays. In Java, a two-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays, a three-dimensional array is an array of arrays of arrays, a four-dimensional array is an array of arrays of arrays of arrays, and so on...

We can define a two-dimensional array as:

1. `int[ ] num[ ] = {{1,2}, {1,2}, {1,2}, {1,2}}`
2. `int[ ][ ] num = new int[4][2]`

   ```
   num[0][0] = 1;
   num[0][1] = 2;
   num[1][0] = 1;
   num[1][1] = 2;
   num[2][0] = 1;
   num[2][1] = 2;
   num[3][0] = 1;
   num[3][1] = 2;
   ```

   If you don't allocate, let's say `num[2][1]`, it is not initialized and then it is automatically allocated 0, that is, automatically `num[2][1] = 0`;
3. Below, `num1.length` gives you rows.
4. While `num1[0].length` gives you the number of elements related to `num1[0]`. Here `num1[0]` has related arrays `num1[0][0]` and `num[0][1]` only.
5. Here we used a `for` loop which helps us to calculate `num1[i].length`. Here `i` is incremented through a loop.

   ```
   class array
   {
       static int[][] add(int[][] num1,int[][] num2)
       {
           int[][] temp = new int[num1.length][num1[0].length];
           for(int i = 0; i<temp.length; i++)
           {
               for(int j = 0; j<temp[i].length; j++)
               {
                   temp[i][j] = num1[i][j]+num2[i][j];
               }
           }
           return temp;
       }

       public static void main(String args[])
       {
           /* We can define a two-dimensional array as
                1.  int[] num[] = {{1,2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}}
                2.  int[][] num = new int[4][2]
                    num[0][0] = 1;
                    num[0][1] = 2;
                    num[1][0] = 1;
                    num[1][1] = 2;
                    num[2][0] = 1;
                    num[2][1] = 2;
                    num[3][0] = 1;
                    num[3][1] = 2;

                    If you don't allocate let's say num[2][1] is
                    not initialized, and then it is automatically
                    allocated 0, that is, automatically num[2][1] = 0;
                 3. Below num1.length gives you rows
                 4. While num1[0].length gives you number of elements
                    related to num1[0]. Here num1[0] has related arrays
                    num1[0][0] and num[0][1] only.
                 5. Here we used a 'for' loop which helps us to calculate
                    num1[i].length, and here i is incremented through a loop.
           */
           int num1[][] = {{1,2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}};
           int num2[][] = {{1,2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}};

           int num3[][] = add(num1,num2);
           for(int i = 0; i<num1.length; i++)
           {
               for(int j = 0; j<num1[j].length; j++)
                   System.out.println("num3[" + i + "][" + j + "]=" + num3[i][j]);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I'll add that if you want to read the dimensions, you can do this:

```
int[][][] a = new int[4][3][2];

System.out.println(a.length);  // 4
System.out.println(a[0].length); // 3
System.out.println(a[0][0].length); //2
```

You can also have [jagged arrays](http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/0020__Language-Basics/Jagged_array.htm), where different rows have different lengths, so `a[0].length != a[1].length`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int[][] myNums = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11} };
 for (int x = 0; x < myNums.length; ++x) {
    for(int y = 0; y < myNums[i].length; ++y) {
       System.out.print(myNums[x][y]);
    }
 }
```

Output

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
5
6
7
8
9
10
11