# Create n amount of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I would like to know how, if possible, to create a n amount of arrays of the same size. Help would be greatly appreciated. For example: I want to create 10 arrays with the same amount of elements without having to create them one by one: `int[] a = new int[]`. Hope this is more clear now.

One of my questions in one of the comments was +- "how do I sort the array row for row / column for column". I figured it out - maybe someone may find it useful.

```
int[] sortarr = new int[5]; //create array to transfer data from row to new array

for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
    sortarr[j] = hands[i][j]; //transfer the data from 2D array's row to sortarr
    }
    Arrays.sort(sortarr); //sort the row's data

    for (int x=0; x<5; x++){ 
    hands[i][x] = sortarr[x]; //transfer the data back to 2D array
    }

}
```

Maybe it's pretty obvious, but I hope this will help someone out there.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Could you give more information? Do you need a variable number of arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a 2D array.

```
int n;
int size;
int[][] arr = new int[size][n];
```

You can fill the array with a nested `for` loop;

```
for(int i =0;i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; i < arr[i].length; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = someValue;
    }
}
```

Or you could populate the arrays like so:

```
int[][] arr2 = new int[n][];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    arr2[i] = new int[size];
}
```

You can think of a 2D array as an array of arrays, for example:

```
private Card[][] allPlayerHands;
public Card[] getHand(int playerNumber) {
    return allPlayerHands[playerNumber];
}
```

Here is a good Stack Overflow question about 2D arrays:

> [Initialising a multidimensional array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067073/java-multidimensional-array)

Comment: I'm not sure that an 2D array will work. I want to shuffle a deck and now deal the cards to 5 different people. That five cards need to be saved each in its own array.

Comment: @ISJ, you can think of a 2D array as an array of arrays.  See my edit.

Comment: @ISJ made another edit in the middle of the post for creating many 1D arrays in a 2D array.

Comment: @jjnguy, thanks a lot. So I can just save player one's cards in the first row. Player two's cards in row in the second row, etc. Thus: int[][] a = new int[players][5] - 5 card poker

Comment: @jjnguy - sorry for bothering, but I have another question concerning a 2D array. How do I sort the array row for row? Thanks, ISJ

Comment: @ISJ, check out, `Arrays.sort()`.  You can pass in one of the arrays that is part of the 2D array and it will only sort that part.

Comment: @ISJ, but if you want to sort each array in the 2D array, that's a different issue.

Comment: @jjnguy Thanks for all the help. I figured it out. I pasted the code in my question

Answer (score 3):

2D array is the answer. Let me try to explain

you need to deal the deck to 5 different people i.e. int people[5].

now consider, that each 5 people have 5 cards i.e

```
Guy 1: 1,2,3,4,5
Guy 2: 1,2,3,4,5
Guy 3: 1,2,3,4,5
Guy 4: 1,2,3,4,5
Guy 5: 1,2,3,4,5
```

i.e.

```
people[1]: 1,2,3,4,5
people[2]: 1,2,3,4,5
people[3]: 1,2,3,4,5
people[4]: 1,2,3,4,5
people[5]: 1,2,3,4,5
```

i.e.

```
people[5][5]
```

now if you have to access, card 3 of person 1 then it would be

```
people[0][2] // u know its zero based aray
```

Answer (score 0):

Two dimensional array

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D.html

Comment: Haha, search google and post a link to the first result.  Good effort.

Answer (score 0):

int[] i = {1,2,3,4,5}

int[] j = i.clone()

You will get the size alone with the contents