# String and Integer inside a multi-level array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to do a little more than required for an assignment in class. Ultimately I'm going to have the following random for stats. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do math to the number part of my array. Right now, I'm using a String to store the array and the number values are being stored as strings. I've tried doing an Object[][] .... and I can't figure out how to do math on the object.

Is there a way to store some values of a multidimensional (stacked?) array as strings and others as integers?

I know it's not showing only the even objects of the array. I changed the code around so it'd be easier to get help with. I do have this working in my version at home.

I tried using the information found on [Initialising a multidimensional array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067073/java-multidimensional-array) but it does not give a solution that I could make work.

Thank you very much!

```
import java.util.Random;

public class StackedArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] stats = new String[][] { { "Str", "6" }, { "Con", "3" },
                { "Int", "5" }, { "Wis", "8" }, { "Dex", "2" },
                { "pAtk", "0" }, { "mAtk", "0" }, { "AC", "0" },
                { "Mana", "0" }, { "HP", "0" } };

        System.out.println("There are " + stats.length
                + " objects in the array.");
        System.out.println("The first object in the array is: " + stats[0][0]
                + ".");
        System.out.print("Even objects in array are:  ");

        for (int i = 0; i < stats.length; i = i + 1) {
            if (i <= stats.length - 3) {
                stats[i][1] = (stats[i][1]);
                System.out.print(stats[i][1] + ", ");
            } else
                System.out.println(stats[i][1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you requiring a `Map<String, Integer>` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a `Map<String, Integer>` or modify

```
    for(int i=0; i < stats.length; i = i + 1) {
        if ( i <= stats.length - 3) {
            stats[i][1] = (stats[i][1]);
            System.out.print(stats[i][1] + ", ");
        }
        else System.out.println(stats[i][1]);
    }
```

to

```
    for(int i=0; i < stats.length; i = i + 1) {
        if ( i <= stats.length - 3) {
            try {
                System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(stats[i][1]) + ", ");
            } catch(NumberFormatException ignore){/* ignore this */}
        }
        else {
            try {
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(stats[i][1]) + ", ");
            } catch(NumberFormatException ignore){/* ignore this */}
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works great thank you very much for the help. I was trying to do something similar but I had the Integer.parseInt in the wrong place and I wasn't using the catch.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use "HashMap" since it can define types for both keys and values

```
HashMap<String, Integer> stats = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
stats.put("Str", 6);
stats.put("Con", 3);
// And so on...
System.out.println( ""+(stats.get("Str")+1) ); //4
```

Comment: I'm playing around with HashMap and its pretty slick so far. I'm required to use an array with this assignment and I've got a lot reading to do to figure out what HashMap can do since I never heard of it until your post. I've changed mine around so that it works well using HashMap. Thanks for the response / info!