# Java - 3D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067073/java-multidimensional-array)

I was looking for a good tutorial on 3D arrays in Java but till now couldn't find any. Are there resources or tutorials you recommend for describing this subject?

Thanks.