# Java array with empty second brackets

Tags: java

In Java you can do this

```
int[][] i = new int[10][];
```

Does this just create 10 empty arrays of int? Does it have other implications?

Comment: It should be int[][] i = new int[10][];

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7913679/1427124

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It creates a 10-entry array of `int[]`. Each of those 10 array references will initially be `null`. You'd then need to create them (and because Java doesn't have true multidimensional arrays, each of those 10 `int[]` entries can be of any length).

So for instance:

```
int i[][] = new int [10][];
i[0] = new int[42];
i[1] = new int[17];
// ...and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

Executing your code creates an array of size 10, each element of which *can* hold a reference to a `int[]`, but which are all initialized to null.

In order to *use* the int[]s, you would have to create new int[] for each of the element, something like this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
    i[n] = new int[10]; // make them as large as you need
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does; however, each of those arrays are null. You have to then initialize each of those sub-arrays, by saying int[10][0] = new int[MY_SIZE], or something similar. You can have arrays with different lengths inside the main array; for example, this code would work:

```
int[][] i = new int[10][];
for(int ind = 0; ind<10;ind++){
    i[ind]=new int[ind];
}
```

It is just an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here you create ten `new int[0]` arrays. You have to manually initialize it, it's useful when you don't need square matrix:

```
    int[][] array = new int[10][];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[i];
    }
```

If you need square matrix you can do:

```
    int[][] array = new int[10][10];
```

And it will be initialized with default values.

Answer (score 0):

That is just the declaration, you need to initialize it. The 10 arrays would be null initially.

Comment: Since Java isn't C, it will actually initialize all the slots to 0, or `null`, depending on if it's an `int` or reference type.

Comment: @DaoWen: No, it will initialize the slots to `null`, as `i` is an array of `int[]`. Each of *those* still needs to be created (and when they are, their slots will be initialized to `0`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - You're right, in this case the empty `[]` on the end means there are no actual `ints` present to initialize to 0. I was editing my comment when you replied—thanks for pointing that out though.