# Two dimensional array initializer followed by square brackets

Tags: java, arrays, compilation

I have a problem understanding this piece of code:

```
int[] it = new int[][]{{1}}[0];
```

Why is it compileable, and how can I understand such a declaration?

Comment: Off-topic, but I'm surprised this question is so well-received. It seems most questions these days that are less than four sentences long and/or are about asking "what does this do" get downvoted to oblivion =P.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: I think the enthusiasm for this question is a little overrated, but I can see how this would be a confusing line of code for someone new to Java.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Oh it was confusing to me too when I first saw it, so I guess that does mean something!

Comment: @theGreenCabbage sufficiently interesting questions **are** above the law

Comment: @theGreenCabbage give programmers a fitting puzzle and they'll drool. ;) (BTW this question is now featured on all SE sites)

Comment: Well, I certainly am interested in it, but I'm wondering why such a declaration would be used. It's essentially a really confusing way of storing a single variable into a mult-dimen. What could this be used for?

Comment: I really hope you found that in some book of "Java Tricks" or something, and it's not some actual production code someone wrote.

Comment: This could be a simplified example of the concrete situation. For example he might make a 2x2 field like this and get the first row: `int[] it = new int[][]{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}[0];` It's not very common, but it's not the most unreadable code either.

Comment: You assign the value of the first element "[0]" of two dimensional array "[][]" which first element is an array "{{}}" with one element in it which is an array "{1}" with one element "1" to a newly declared variable "int[]" named "it". In the result the "it" is a one element array: {1};

Comment: wouldn't `int[] it = new int[] {1};` be more concise?

Comment: How can this question not be a duplicate more than five years after Stack Overflow started and with approximately 528571 Java questions? We need a human search in this case - Google is not much help. A starting point may be [an answer to *Initialising a multidimensional array in Java*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067073/initialising-a-multidimensional-array-in-java/1067729#1067729) which has a similar contruct.

Comment: @user2654250 Be advised that you can accept an answer if it answers your question.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage I think the reason is the esoteric look of the code which actually compiles.

Comment: Wow, I assumed at first glance it was something new from C++11.

Comment: @Chris Consider this code then: `private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(){{
  add("Something");
 }};`. This is almost as esoteric like the one in the question. The first brace creates an anonymous instance of `ArrayList` while the second one is an instance initializer block (that's why you can use `add` without a reference).

Comment: @AdamArold You can't fool me with that one, I recognize it from using JMock. :) Don't think I've ever used it in any other context apart from JMock, tho.

Comment: I use it elsewhere: in Mockito HAHA.

Answer (score 102):

What you are doing here is:

1. Declaring a new variable `int[] it` (which is a one-dimensional array)
2. Assigning its value from the first element `[0]`
3. of the two-dimensional array `new int[][]`
4. which is initialized to be `{{1}}`

So you create a two-dimensional array which you initialize to contain an array which contains `1` and at the same time you take the first element of the *outer* array (which is a one-dimensional array containing `1`) and assign it to your variable.

Comment: Cool. Learned something new today. So technically there's no need for this multidimensional array? The `{{1}}` is simply placing a single `1` into a multi-dimensional. What could/would be the use for such a declaration?

Comment: I don't see any valid purpose for it in this context. It can be useful if you need to supply parameters in this format for some legacy library though.

Comment: Very nice explanation, "as simple as possible, as complex as necessary" :)

Answer (score 30):

```
int[] it = new int[][]{{1}}[0];
```

Let's break this one down into each stage, and what it means.

```
new int[][]
```

This is a new multidimensional array.

```
{{1}}
```

This is a multidimensional array literal. It makes an array that looks like this:

```
[0] = [1]
[1] = []
[2] = []
...
[N] = []
```

So take note, *each* element inside this array is itself an array. Then you've specified that your variable `it` is equal to the first array in the multidimensional array, so it equates directly to:

```
int[] it = new int[] {1};
```

Comment: At the time of posting, I didn't really see any other answers that broke down the statement like this.

Comment: I like these types of explanations. I definitely emulate this type of answer style when I try to explain something that breaks down individual elements that are properly structured. Sometimes I learn something on the mean time that I break it down! I also make use of it when I try to debug my own code.

Comment: Nice breakdown, but you mistyped the initializer: {{1}}, not {{0}}.

Comment: I find the part "_`{{1}}` […] makes an array that looks like this: […] `[10] = []`_" is misleading: There is no such thing as `[10]` because the outer array is only of size 1, so the only element is at index 0 (and contains another array of size 1 containing the integer 1, as you stated correctly). While I'm already at nitpicking, I think you missed to update the very last line (should be `{1}`, not `{0}`). And one last note, just for fun: You can even shorten the line to just `int[] it = {1};` (this only works while declaring  an array variable, in all other cases you'll need `new int[]{…}`).

Comment: While I appreciate you taking the time to read my answer, only the `{1}` criticism is valid. With the `0-10` I was trying to illustrate the point that the rest of it is empty.. which I did. Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

The `new int[][]{{1}}` allocates a new 1x1 2D array. The (only) element is set to 1.

The `[0]` returns a reference to the first (and the only) row, which is of type `int[]`.

The `int[] it = ...` declares a variable and initializes it with the above reference.

The end result is equivalent to `int[] it = new int[]{1}`.

Comment: @kai: the result is a 1D array, but you're using a 2D array.

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, you are creating an anonymous two-dimensional array (`new int[][]{{1}}`) and then taking the first element of that two-dimensional array (`{1}`) and assigning it to the variable `it`.

Let's go step-by-step, because this actually is kind of confusing.

`new int[][]{{1}}`: This creates a two-dimensional array which has only one element: an array, which contains one array, which contains one `int` (the number 1).  Because it's not assigned to a variable anywhere and won't be accessible past this statement, we call it "anonymous", and it has the smallest scope possible.

`[0]`: This accesses the first element of the anonymous two-dimensional array we created above.  The first element is a *one*-dimensional array containing 1 (i.e., `{1}`).

`int[] it =`: Finally, here we take that retrieved one-dimensional array and store it in our variable.

As a side note, there's absolutely no reason to do it this way, and it seems like just a very interesting Java puzzle.

Answer (score 6):

I will try to break it down

```
new int[][] // an array of arrays (or 2-dimensional array)
{1} // an array instance with a single element: 1
{{1}} // an array instance with a single element: above array instance
[0] // the first element of an array
```

So it is roughly equivalent to the following code:

```
int[] inner = new int[1]; // an empty array with length 1
inner[0] = 1;
int[][] outer = new int[1][];
outer[0] = inner;

int[] it = outer[0];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int[] it = new int[][]{{1}}[0];
```

The integer array `it` gets assigned the following:

```
new int[][] // A new 2D array is created
{{1}} // This is an initializer. The first array in the first array gets an array of 1 item: '1'
[0] // Take the first array from the 2D array
```