# Creating an Array of existing Objects Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm not sure whether this is even possible or not... I'm only starting to program in Java.

So my question is. I created this multidimensional array which contains objects.

Could you please check it and see what am I doing wrong?

```
Object data[][] = 
{"Item#1", jackets.getDescription(), jackets.getUnitOnHand(), jackets.getPrice(0) }
{"Item#2", designerJeans.getDescription(), designerJeans.getUnitOnHand(), designerJeans.getPrice(0)};
```

Could you tell me whats wrong in the above code?

Comment: You're missing an outer pair of curly braces

Comment: For this, look into maps.

Comment: This should probably be a `Map<String, Clothing>`, where clothing is an `interface` that captures the contract of your clothing items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[][][] threeDimArr = { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }, { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } };
```

([Initialising a multidimensional array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067073/initialising-a-multidimensional-array-in-java))

So obviously you have to add outer brackets.

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate; you should flag to close instead of posting the link as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another more { and } and also have to use a comma in between like {}, {}

For example:

```
Object data[][] = {{"2","3"},{"1","2"}};
                  ^         ^         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object data[][] = 
{
    {"Item#1", jackets.getDescription(), //... },
    {"Item#2", designerJeans.getDescription(), //...}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate the sub arrays into the array:

```
Object data[][] = {{"Item#1", jackets.getDescription(), jackets.getUnitOnHand(), jackets.getPrice(0)},
    {"Item#2", designerJeans.getDescription(), designerJeans.getUnitOnHand(), designerJeans.getPrice(0)}};
```