# 2d array initialization in java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

```
int plate[8][8]={
           {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
           {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
           {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
           {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
           {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
           {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
           {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
           {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
           };
```

I want to initialize 2d array in java.How can alter this to make it right?
       thank u.

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067073/initialising-a-multidimensional-array-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Two-Dimensional Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/creating-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: Have you even bothered to google your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `int plate[7][7]` to `int[][] plate` or `int plate[][]`. Both are correct.

Comment: and remove the `,` from after the final entry to the array

Comment: Yes, but this is not neccessary, just prettier.

Comment: oh, that doesn't cause syntax error? Nevermind then.