# How loop through an array of objects, and add a ref name

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, polymorphism, arrayobject

I have a for loop that adds values to an array of objects.
Say I have class B, and make a array of class B inside class A.
like

```
    B array1 = new B[10];
```

How can I name each object with a reference name that will look like

```
for(int x = 0; x<array1.length; x++){
    B object+x = new Bar(int value1, int value2);
    x++;
}
```

each time it goes through the for-loop
I'm not sure how to add a number after "object" so that I can have 10 array objects like object1, object2, object3...

I want to be able to reference these saved objects inside another method in class A, without creating a new object each time, and then call a method from class B on the object.
Sorry I cant provide much code, its part of a assignment and I cant post my code.

Comment: how about using an array of arrays? (aka https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067073/initialising-a-multidimensional-array-in-java)

Comment: You can't do something like that.  The closest thing you have to that is an array.

Comment: @JoeC what do you mean? My teachers have said to create an array like this.

Comment: Why do you want do that?The item of array have a reference named array[index],why do you want another reference to point it?

Comment: Java can't do that (although [Rexx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rexx) can!). Exactly why do you want to "name" the `B` instances? If you really need to access them by name, use a `Map<String, B>`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot this. In Java you cannot create variables with dynamic names calculated in runtime. If you think your teacher asked this of you, it is very likely a misunderstanding.

The closest would be probably something like:

```
Bar[] array1 = new Bar[10];

for(int x = 0; x<array1.length; x++){
    array1[x] = new Bar(...);
}
```