# 7-dimensional vector Java

Tags: java, arrays, vector, n-dimensional

I am very new to java and I have this assignment which I have been working on very intensivly for the last 14 days.

The assignement is to build a class vector with max. 7 dimensions:
what I came with to make the vector multi-dimensional is that I declared 7 variables

```
private double x, y,z,i,j,k,f;
```

which then I will initialize in constructors etc..
Well, my first question: did I build a 7 dimensional vector in this way?

OR,

should I somehow work with arrays for this problem
like declaring an array;

```
double [][] = data; // which generates a 2D-Vector.
```

AND,

```
double [][][][][][][] = data1; //which declare a 7D-Vector??!!!
```

for any helpful information I will be very thankful

thanks all and
Best regards to you  :)

Comment: Check the answer on this question: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7913679/4250184)

Comment: Define "vector" - do you mean it in the sense of a mathematical ordered tuple like (1,2,3)? Or in the sense of eg. c++ and Java `Vector` class which stores a list of values?

Comment: 1. No.  2.  Maybe ... depending on what `data` is.

Answer (score 1):

> did I build a 7 dimensional vector in this way?

Yes you have.  A [vector](http://mathinsight.org/vector_introduction) is a way of storing a magnitude and direction, which is done by correctly assigning the value and sign of each `double`.  A vector in 2-space would require two values, and a vector in 7-space would require 7 values, which you have.

> should I somehow work with arrays for this problem like declaring an array;

You can, but you don't need a multi-dimensional array.  To store a single vector in a 7-space, you just need an array of length 7:

```
double[] data = new double[7]; // store a 7D vector
```

You could then modify your existing code, replacing `x` with `data[0]`, `y` with `data[1]` and so on.

Comment: Thanks alot azurefrog. That clarifies alot for me 

Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a multidimensional array for a vector. *By definition*, a vector has only a single column; if it had multiple columns, it would be a matrix, not a vector.

If you want a vector of size `n`, just create a single-dimensional array of size `n`. You *could* use an ArrayList or something like that, but there's less of a point because you (presumably) know the size of the vector in advance. (If that's *not* the case, ArrayList could be good).

The most interesting part of a Vector class is actually the operations, so use whatever data structure allows you to retain order and conveniently perform your operations. Truthfully, that'll probably be an array of size *n*.