# How to append to array of arrays instance variable?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I have an instance variable inside a class that looks like

```
private GridLocation [][] world;
```

I'm not sure how you add values to a pair of angle brackets like that. I just know that the two values represent the coordinates of a square in a grid. How would you add the square (1,2) for example? According to my book, you assign values inside the constructor with

```
this.name = name;
```

I'm very unsure what to do in this case though

Comment: `world[1][2] = yourGridLocation;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @GBlodgett already answered the question. It is a "multidimensional" Array or array of arrays. It works like a single array where you can choose between different arrays.

```
 GridLocation [][] world = new GridLocation[x][y];//x, and y are the size of your array


 world[1][2] = yourGridLocation;
```

you should also have a look how to initialise it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067073/initialising-a-multidimensional-array-in-java) is a link to a similiar question.

> In Java, a two-dimensional array is represented by an array of arrays
>   in which every sub-array is of the same length:
>   [quote](http://www.dsearls.org/courses/C113Java/QuickReference/ArrayOfArrays/ArrayOfArrays.htm)
>   [image]